# How to delete one object from a Surface instance?

Tags: python, pygame

There is an instance of the Surface class, and there are also several instances of the Rect class on it. `Surface.fill([color])` will hide all elements that are on the Surface. But i need to hide only one Rect instance. How can I remove **just one specific** Rect element from Surface?

Answer (score 1):

> `Surface.fill([color])` will hide all elements that are on the Surface [...]

No, it does not. A [`Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) does not contain any object, a `Surface` is just a bunch of pixel organized in rows and columns.  [`fill`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.fill) just changes the color of all pixels. You cannot "delete" an object from a surface. You can just paint on the Surface in a different color.
If you want to change the color of a rectangular region of a `Surface` object, then you can paint a rectangle on the `Surface` by [`pygame.draw.rect()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html#pygame.draw.rect).

If you have a dynamic scene with dynamic objects, then common way is to redraw to entire scene in every frame. Implement and application loop. The application loop has to:

- handle the events by either [`pygame.event.pump()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.pump) or [`pygame.event.get()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get).
- update the game states and positions of objects dependent on the input events and time (respectively frames)
- clear the entire display or draw the background
- draw the entire scene (`blit` all the objects)
- update the display by either [`pygame.display.update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.update) or [`pygame.display.flip()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.flip)